# How to find the range of this specific function?

Tags: functions

$$f(x) = (x-1)e^{x+2} - \frac {x^2}2 $$

if x is in the domain of $[-2,1]$

[Image of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzZoQ.png)

Thank you.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Can you, for example, find the absolute max and min of the function over the given region?

Comment: hint: continuity, monotony on intervals between neighboring extrema, values at local extrema, boundary values

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Caclulate $f(x=-2)$ and $f(x=1)$ first, because the function is continous you know the range is at least $[f(x=-2),f(x=1)]$.

Then find the derivative $f'(x)$ and find zeros of the derivative. These zeros (critical point) indicate a potential maximum/minimum of your function. To check what type of critical point you have you can use the second derivative test $f''(x_{critical})>0$ implies a minimum and $f''(x_{critical})<0$ implies a maximum.

Can you complete the task from here?

Answer (score 0):

Finding critical points firstly because i would find max/min values in the given domain. $ \frac{d}{dx}( (x-1) e^{x+2} - \frac{x^2}{2})  = 0 
\\$

$ \Leftrightarrow 
\\$

$ e^{x+2} + (x-1) e^{x+2} - x =0$

x=-2 or x=0

I would just check the values in x=-2,0,1. Since it's a pretty easy task, even though MrYouMath is completely right

Answer (score 0):

By computing $f'(x)$ you may easily check that $f(x)$ is decreasing on $[-2,0]$ and increasing on $[0,1]$. Since $f(-2)\in (f(0),f(1))$, it follows that the range of $f$ is $\color{red}{[f(0),f(1)]}$.